# MVC 3 Two models in one view and action method overloading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have "reset password" and "user profile info update" sections on one view.

I have a parent model with two child models: ResetPwdModel and UserInfoModel.

For both reset password submit and save profile info submit, I want the result URL to look the same (same as the current URL), so the users won't be confused.

In an effort to achieve this, I overloaded the action methods with one accepting ResetPwdModel and the other accepting UserInfoModel. However, I get the error message `The current request for action 'profile' on controller type 'XXController' is ambiguous...`

Is there an elegant way to resolve this? My goal is to be able to use two models in 1 view and have the  post URL looking the same as current URL.

**Model**

```
public class ProfileParentModel
{
    public ProfileResetPwdModel ResetPwd { get; set; }
    public ProfileUserInfoModel UserInfo { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileResetPwdModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Profile_lbl_OldPassword", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Profile_lbl_NewPassword", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessageResourceName = "Profile_Error_NotMatch", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Profile_lbl_ConfirmNewPassword", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string ConfirmNewPassword { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileUserInfoModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Profile_lbl_FirstName", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Profile_lbl_LastName", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Profile_lbl_WorkTitle", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string WorkTitle { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Profile_lbl_CompanyName", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Profile_lbl_CompanyAddress", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@{
    var passwordHtml = Html.HtmlHelperFor(Model.ResetPwd);
    var profileHtml = Html.HtmlHelperFor(Model.UserInfo);
}
@using (passwordHtml.BeginForm())
{
    //HTML goes here...
}
@using (profileHtml.BeginForm())
{
   //HTML goes here...
}
```

**Controller**

```
        [ActionName("Profile")]
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult ResetPassword(ProfileResetPwdModel model)
    {

        return View("Profile", parentModel);
    }

    [ActionName("Profile")]
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult SaveUserInfo(ProfileUserInfoModel model)
    {
        return View("Profile", parentModel);
    }
```

Comment: Please post some code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your action method names are irrelevant to what you want the response URL to be.

First, are you submitting data using two separate Html forms? I would say this is the best way, and point each to a different action. Your action can then redirect to whichever action you want.

Next, you wont be able to specify the child models as parameters for the action as the framework will not be able to automatically work out the properties (because you use a parent model to begin with) but this actually depends on how you define the names of your form fields.

If you are using the `Html.TextBoxFor` methods for example. then this will give a field name of 'parent.childproperty'. In this case you should use the parent model as a parameter for both actions:

```
public ActionResult ResetPassword(ParentModel model)...
public ActionResult UpdateInfo(ParentModel model)...
```

If you are happy to manually set the field names yourself, to match the child class properties then you can use the child models as parameterss:

```
public ActionResult ResetPassword(ResetPwdModel model)...
public ActionResult UpdateInfo(UserInfoModel model)...
```

with fields set like:

```
@Html.TextBox("NewPassword", Model.ResetPwdModel.NewPassword)
```

and they will map correctly.

after processing each action just add the following at the end:

```
return RedirectToAction("Profile");
```

Comment: Yes I'm submitting using two separate HTML forms. I use the HTML Helper in MVCUtil

Comment: Right now if I post to ResetPassword, my return URL ends with "/ResetPassword" and same is true for updateInfo...how can I make the URL to stay /Profile?...what am I missing...Thanks!

Comment: @Laguna: As I said, you have to return `RedirectToAction` and pass whatever the name of the action you want to show. With your updated question you should pass "Profile"

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to make a redirect at the end of each action.

```
public ViewResult Profile()
{
   ...get the profile info of the user from db
   return View(profile);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(ProfileResetPwdModel model)
{
   ...reset the password
   return RedirectToAction("Profile");
}

public ActionResult SaveUserInfo(ProfileUserInfoModel model)
{
   ...update the profile
   return RedirectToAction("Profile");
}
```

By this way user won't get confused.

Answer (score 0):

The View() method of Controller [has overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460310%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) has overload that accepts name of view as argument. So you can use the same view in different actions.

Comment: This will not change the url though